# Django request.POST.get SQL injection

Tags: python, django

I'm currently getting POST data using the method request.POST.get(). I'd like to know if this method gives me raw POST data or if it's correctly escaping and protected against SQL injection.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Galaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're feeding the result of `request.POST` right into a SQL query (i.e., without using the Django ORM), you will most definitely be vulnerable to SQL injection.

But, if you *are* using the Django ORM (or another well-written ORM, such as SQLAlchemy), all of your input data will be sanitized.

tldr; you're safe

Comment: I'm using the Django ORM so I'm safe! Thank you very much!